# Newton's method $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^8 + \frac{8}{5} x ^5+ 3 x +10$ near the point $x = 3.$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, linear-approximation

$\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^8 + \frac{8}{5} x ^5+ 3 x +10$ near the point $x = 3.$

Use $x_1 = 3$ as the initial approximation. Find the next two approximations, $x_2$ and $x_3$, to four decimal places each.

And I get both of them wrong, why?

I used formula that is derived from linearization:

$x_1 = x_0 - \frac {f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)} $

For the $x_2$ this is how I solve:

$x_2$ = $3 - \frac {f(3)}{f'(3)}$ = $3 - \frac {\frac{36883}{10}}{9399}$ = 2.6076

f(3) = [$\frac{36883}{10}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2%203%5E8%20%2B%208%2F5%203%5E5%20%2B%203*3%20%2B%2010%20)

f'(3) = [9399](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%204*%203%5E7%2B8%20*3%5E4%2B3%20)

but it's not correct, why?

Comment: Start with $x_0 = 3$; what you have computed is correct for $x_1$.

Comment: @Arkamis but I'm told that I can use $x_1$ = 3. Anyhow, I got 2.2572 for $x_2$ but it was still incorrect.

Comment: Are the plus signs correct? Then there is no positive solution, and also no root close to $3$.

Comment: Moreover, this function has a positive minimum close to $x=-1.4$, and thus no real roots at all, the closest you get is $x=- 1.4127366 \pm 0.2905569*i$.

Comment: You either need to choose $x_0 = 3$, in which case you should compute $x_1$ to be about $2.607$, or you choose $x_1 = 3$, in which case $x_2 = 2.607$. You always compute the next index from where you are. You need to clean up your notation to have any hope of solving the problem.